# VBScript to isolate rest of the string

Tags: string, vbscript

I have part of a script

```
strRel = "\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.4100.4126.105\Bin64\"
strArray = Split(strRel,"\",-1,1)
strCom = strArray(1)

wscript.echo "strCom is " & strCom
```

Which will output

```
strCom is Program Files (x86)
```

How do I modify the Split function so it outputs

```
strCom is \Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.4100.4126.105\Bin64\
```

Please note the script processes various directories, with various sub-folders.

Comment: So are you just trying to remove the very first folder from your path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're trying to do, but if you're just trying to strip off the first folder in your path, you can use this. It just gets the length of the first folder and returns the path after that point.

```
strRel = "\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.4100.4126.105\Bin64\"
strArray = Split(strRel, "\")

' Add 2 to the length to account for the delimiter (\) and the one-baseness of Mid()...
strCom = Mid(strRel, Len(strArray(1)) + 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the substring VB script like in this  [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/vbScript/showasp.asp?filename=demo_vb_mid), except do `Mid(strRel,21)`

Comment: I'll be working with strings of multiple sizes ... I'm looking to see if there is a string length function in VBscript

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the number of fields [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0764e5w5%28v=vs.84%29) creates:

```
strRel = "\Program Files (x86)\Symantec\Symantec Endpoint Protection\12.1.4100.4126.105\Bin64\"
strArray = Split(strRel, "\", 3)
strCom = "\" & strArray(2)

WScript.Echo "strCom is " & strCom
```